# What's wrong with Angular service test?

Tags: unit-testing, service, mocking, angularjs, jasmine

I've got a service calling external web service:

```
angular.module('myApp.services', [])
.service('autoCmpltDataSvc', function ($http) {
    var innerMatch = function (data) {
        return $.map(data, function (item) {
            return {
                fullName: item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName,
                shortName: item.name,
                itemId: item.geonameId
            };
        });
    };

    this.fetchFromGeonamesDb = function (request, response, matcher) {
        $http({
            method: 'jsonp',
            url: 'http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON?callback=JSON_CALLBACK',
            params: {
                featureClass: "P",
                style: "full",
                maxRows: 12,
                name_startsWith: request.destName
            }
        }).success(function (data, status) {
            console.log(data);
            response($.map(innerMatch(data.geonames), matcher));
        });
    };
});
```

I'm trying to test that it correctly forms the output, so I mock the call to real web service. 
Here is my unit-test.

```
describe('Services', function () {

    beforeEach(module('myApp.services'));

    describe('autoCompleteService', function () {
        var $httpBackend, svc;
        var results = [];
        var matcher = function (item) {
            return item;
        };
        var response = function (arr) {
            results = arr;
        };

        beforeEach(inject(function ($injector, autoCmpltDataSvc) {
            svc = autoCmpltDataSvc;
            $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
            $httpBackend.whenJSONP(/searchJSON/).
              respond([
              { name: 'City1', adminName1: 'Region1', countryName: 'Country1', geonameId: 1 },
              { name: 'City2', countryName: 'Country2', geonameId: 2}]);
        }));

        afterEach(function () {
            $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
            $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
        });

        it('should return values', function () {
            $httpBackend.expectJSONP(/searchJSON/);
            svc.fetchFromGeonamesDb({ 'destName': 'fra' }, response, matcher);
            $httpBackend.flush();
            expect(results.length).toBe(2);
        });
    });
});
```

But the test produces an error.

```
         TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
            at Function.v.extend.map (C:/Users/kmukhort/Documents/_files/TMate/A
ngularTest/app/lib/jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2:15334)
            at innerMatch (C:/Users/kmukhort/Documents/_files/TMate/AngularTest/
app/js/services.js:8:18)
```

I suppose it's something wrong with mock respond, as it seems it doesn't return the array.
But I can't understand why it doesn't return the array.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your example helped me to mock a service. Thx :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to Peter Bacon Darwin my silly mistake was found.

> OK so your success function is expecting your http call to return an
>   object with a field called geonames, currently your mock is returning
>   a straight array.
>
> Perhaps you should change your mock to this?

```
> $httpBackend.whenJSONP(/searchJSON/).
>               respond( { geonames: [
>                 { name: 'City1', adminName1: 'Region1', countryName: 'Country1', geonameId: 1 },
>                 { name: 'City2', countryName: 'Country2', geonameId: 2}]
>               });
```

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/u-fYR-AC8Ec